Use Series[] using noncommutative multiplication
Let's consider Newton's method for systems of nonlinear equations
$$y^{(k)}=x^{(k)}-[F'(x^{(k)}]^{-1}F(x^{(k)}).$$
And I want to use Taylor series for the above method. So considering that
$$F( x^{(k)})=F'(\alpha) \left( e^{(k)}+C_2{e^{(k)}}^2+C_3 {e^{(k)}}^3+C_4 {e^{(k)}}^4+C_5{e^{(k)}}^5\right)+O \left( {e^{(k)}}^6\right)$$
and$$ F'( x^{(k)})=F'(\alpha) \left( I+2C_2{e^{(k)}}+3C_3 {e^{(k)}}^2+4C_4 {e^{(k)}}^3+5C_5{e^{(k)}}^4\right)+O \left( {e^{(k)}}^5 \right).$$
And the inserse of $F'(x^{(k)})$ is
$$F'( x^{(k)})^{-1}=\left( I-2C_2{e^{(k)}}+(4C_2^2-3C_3){e^{(k)}}^2+(-8C_2^3+6C_2C_3+6C_3C_2-4C_4){e^{(k)}}^3\right)F'(\alpha)^{-1} +O \left( {e^{(k)}}^4 \right).$$
I used this code
f[e_] := df[a] (e +C2 e^2+C3 e^3+C4 e^4+C5 e^5);
d = Series[f[e]/f'[e], {e, 0, 5}];

But in this case $C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4, C_5$ are matrices and then $C_2 C_3 \neq C_3C_2$ and therefore I do not get the expected results. I saw this post How to force Series[] to compute expansions by considering non commutative multiplication? But it's not very useful to me, because later I have to find $F(y^{(k)})$ and get incoherent expressions.If anyone has an idea how to do this I would be very grateful.
